# WYSIWYG Image positioning solution?

Tags: javascript, css, image, positioning, wysiwyg

For an Augmented Reality CMS I'm working on I'm looking for a special type of WYSIWYG editor.

I need to be able to position images over a background image, resize/organize them and be able to read out their relative positions.
No text/html editing at all.

Flash solutions are a last resort for I'm sure this can be done with HTML and Javascript

Does anyone know about such a solution?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Menno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...afraid you'll have to roll up your sleeves and roll your own for the most part, but something like this http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/ might get you going. It's jQuery based if you don't mind that, but in principle it's a start (or something similar).

Comment: Thanks, that indeed looks like a useful article. I have achieved pretty much what I wanted using the "contenteditable" tag but there's some browser quirks with that.

Comment: ... cool, was the answer close enough of a lead to warrant acceptance of the answer? ;-)